# how do i change an image in javafx with a button

Tags: java, javafx

trying to be as clear as possible this program should display 4 cards which are selected at random and then underneath them there is a button that resets the all the cards at random from a deck of 52. however I am confused on how to go about this in the action event. (also as an added bonus i cant seem to get the button to display underneath the cards rather i just end up moving the entire screen away from the cards and button) any help would be gratefully appreciated.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class GenerateCards extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Application.launch(args);

    }
public int cardNum(){
     int Num = (int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*52);
     return Num;
}
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        primaryStage.setTitle("Random Card");

                GridPane pane = new GridPane();
                pane.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
                pane.setHgap(10);
                pane.setVgap(5);

                // creates button 
                Button refresh = new Button("Refresh");
               HBox button = new HBox(10);
               button.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER);
               button.getChildren().add(refresh);
               pane.getChildren().add(refresh);

               // creates random card images and adds them to pane
               Image img = new Image("card/"+cardNum()+".png");
               ImageView imgView = new ImageView(img);
               pane.add(imgView, 1, 0);

               Image img2= new Image("card/"+cardNum()+".png");
               ImageView imgView2 = new ImageView(img2);
               pane.add(imgView2, 2, 0);

               Image img3= new Image("card/"+cardNum()+".png");
               ImageView imgView3 = new ImageView(img3);
               pane.add(imgView3, 3, 0);

               Image img4= new Image("card/"+cardNum()+".png");
               ImageView imgView4 = new ImageView(img4);
               pane.add(imgView4,4, 0);
               //create scene
               Scene scene = new Scene(pane,400,200);
               primaryStage.setScene(scene);
               primaryStage.show();
               refresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                        public void handle(ActionEvent e){
                       // where im confused
                        }
                });

    }
}
```

Comment: Use VBox to layout button under the cards. VBox vbox = new VBox(cardsPane, refreshButton);

Comment: the trouble is centering it :/

Comment: vbox.setAlignment()?

Comment: <3 thanks vbox.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_CENTER); did the trick

Comment: Presumably you want to select four different cards.  Your card selection algorithm currently may select the same card twice within the group of four.  See [Example 3-7 Lottery Drawing](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=101766&seqNum=10).  Also, I prefer [`random.nextInt(52) + 1`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt-int-) to `(int) Math.ceil(Math.random()*52)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your button action handler you just have to reset the image inside each image view.

```
refresh.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
        imgView.setImage(new Image("card/" + cardNum() + ".png"));
        imgView2.setImage(new Image("card/" + cardNum() + ".png"));
        imgView3.setImage(new Image("card/" + cardNum() + ".png"));
        imgView4.setImage(new Image("card/" + cardNum() + ".png"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for any one who looks at this later I also had to set my imageViews to final in order to use them within the event.

Comment: Are you still using Java 7? In Java 8 setting them to final should not be necessary anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`Math.random()*4` returns a number between 0 and 4. First, put `img`, `img2`, `img3`, and `img4`to an `ArrayList`. Then get a random index from aforementioned function, get the image at that index in your `ArrayList`, and refresh it.

Comment: I'm sorry i was a bit unclear before I've tried to clear that up in an edit, my issue is i don't know how to go about re displaying my images from the button event. also they should  have a new random number from my cardNum() method